# Org-journal: keeping LOGBOOK drawers when TODO items are carried over

Tags: cl, org-journal

I use org-journal to keep track of my taks (using org-clock).  Org-journal has the option to carry over TODO items from previous dates.  For example, lets say that on Monday I work on my report, and I clock some time.

```
* Monday, 07-09
  :PROPERTIES:
  :CREATED:  20200907
  :END:
** TODO Work on report
   :LOGBOOK:
   CLOCK: [2020-09-07 Mon 11:35]--[2020-09-07 Mon 12:32] =>  0:57
   :END:
```

When I open my journal the next day the TODO item gets carried over, like this:

```
* Monday, 07-09
  :PROPERTIES:
  :CREATED:  20200907
  :END:
* Tuesday, 08-09
  :PROPERTIES:
  :CREATED:  20200908
  :END:
** TODO Work on report
   :LOGBOOK:
   CLOCK: [2020-09-07 Mon 11:35]--[2020-09-07 Mon 12:32] =>  0:57
   :END:
```

The problem is that I lose some of the information of what I did on Monday. When I look at the subheaders under Monday, there is no reference to the report work. True, I can look at the clock entries and figure out from there, but it it would be great to have an option to copy the TODO item to the next day, but keep the LOGBOOK in the previous days (ideally removing the TODO tag), like this:

```
* Monday, 07-09
  :PROPERTIES:
  :CREATED:  20200907
  :END:
** Work on report
   :LOGBOOK:
   CLOCK: [2020-09-07 Mon 11:35]--[2020-09-07 Mon 12:32] =>  0:57
   :END:
* Tuesday, 08-09
  :PROPERTIES:
  :CREATED:  20200908
  :END:
** TODO Work on report
```

This could be achieved by 1) setting the `org-journal-skip-carryover-drawers` so the new entry created on Tuesday does not have a copy of the drawer, like this:

```
(setq org-journal-skip-carryover-drawers (list "LOGBOOK"))
```

and 2) by modyfing the function assigned to the `org-journal-handle-old-carryover` variable, which by default is the `org-journal-delete-old-carryover` function, so the carryover items that have a LOGBOOK drawer are **not** deleted.  This is the function

I have tried with this:

```
(defun org-journal-delete-old-carryover-except-logbook (old_entries)
"Delete all carryover entries from the previous day's journal, except those with a LOGBOOK drawer. 
    
    If the parent heading has no more content, delete it as well."
(mapc (lambda (x)
        (require 'cl-seq)
        (unless (cl-member "LOGBOOK" x :test #'string-match)
      
          (unless (save-excursion
                    (goto-char (1- (cadr x)))
                    (org-goto-first-child))
        
            (kill-region (car x) (cadr x)))
          ))
      (reverse old_entries)))

(setq org-journal-handle-old-carryover 'org-journal-delete-old-carryover-except-logbook)
```

But with this I get the following error

cl-member: Wrong type argument: stringp, 4180

... and I can't figure out why.  How can I keep LOGBOOK drawers when TODO items are carried over?

Comment: The error message is telling you that `cl-member` expected a string (as its first arg), but your code ended up passing it the number 4180 instead.

Comment: Please reformat your code to fix the indentation. You probably copied code with TAB chars. Convert to using the proper number of SPC chars. Thx.

Comment: The doc string for `org-journal-handle-old-carryover` says that the argument of the function  (i,.e. `old_entries` in your code) `... is in form of ((START_POINT (END_POINT . \"TEXT\")) ...);  and in ascending order of START_POINT`. It is *not* a list of strings.

Comment: IOW, instead of `(cl-member "LOGBOOK" x ...)`, try `(cl-member "LOGBOOK" (cadadr x) ...)` . You seem to be doing the right thing with the `START` and `END` points.

Comment: Did you resolve this? An update would be nice.

Comment: Yes! Sorry for the slow report.  I have been on hollidays for a few days and just came back.  Using `(cadadr x)` did the trick.  Thank you @NickD (and also @Drew) for your input.